# squid - http_access

Tags: squid, access-control-list

There is a line in squid default configuration:

```
# Deny CONNECT to other than secure SSL ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
```

acls are applied from top down, so CONNECT acl will deny access to all non SSL and SSL ports. I mean it never reaches the second access rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CONNECT` here means the HTTPS CONNECT method, i.e., the *standardized* way a browser talks to a proxy server, asking for a connection to an HTTPS-serving site

`http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports` means 'deny all HTTPS CONNECT that asks to be connected to a port other than SSL_ports'. If the browser sends a CONNECT method asking to be connected to an SSL_port, the rule doesn't fire.

Whether or not the CONNECT actually gets through depends on the successive `http_access` rules.

Comment: So the acls after `http_access deny` are conjoined with a logical AND. am I right?

Comment: @Majid yes. In general, everything *on the same line* are conjoined with logical AND, while rules *on different lines* are conjoined with logical OR